# redis sorted set highest score

Tags: ruby, redis

Is any simple method to get the highest score from Redis sorted set? I found this way, may be there is better ways to make this(in ruby):

```
all_scores = Redis.zrange('foo', 0, -1, with_scores: true) # => [["item 1", 2.5], ["item 2", 3.4]]
all_scores.flatten.last # => 3.4
```

It seems not the best way.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

you can use **ZREVRANGE** command.

```
ZREVRANGE foo 0 0 withscores
```

This will give you the highest score and it's value.

http://redis.io/commands/zrevrange

Comment: Or get the same effect w/ `ZRANGE foo -1 -1 WITHSCORES`

Answer (score 1):

For Redis 6, this is the command.

```
ZRANGE foo 0 0 REV
```